# Skipping pixels problems

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that will take qr code image and recognize black/white pixels and keep them in an array. But my problem is; I have 294x294 pixel image and one matrix  with fixed size 21x21. So one square module is 294/21=4.0 pixel for me. How can I search pixels by 4.0 pixel to 4.0 pixel? Here is my code:

```
public static void printAllARGBDetails(BufferedImage image) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        System.out.println("Image Dimension: Height-" + height + ", Width-"
                + width);
        System.out.println("Total Pixels: " + (height * width));
        int pixels[][]=new int[21][21];
        int pixel=width/21;
        System.out.println("Pixel=" +pixel);

        for (int i = 20; i>=0 ; i--) {
            for (int j = 20; j>=0 ; j--) {
                if(image.getRGB(i, j)==-1)
                {

                    pixels[i][j]=0;
                }
                else
                {
                    pixels[i][j]=1;
                }

            }
        } 
  }
```

`

Comment: I assume you are doing this just for a proof of concept or an assignment?  If not there is a lot more to consider in a real life situation.  And there are libraries that have already resolved most of these.

Comment: Yes, this is my project assignment.

Answer (score 0):

The edited code below should work but it only tests 1 of the 16 pixels in each element

```
    for (int i = 0; i<20 ; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<20 ; j++) {
            if(image.getRGB(i*4, j*4)==-1)
            {

                pixels[i][j]=0;
            }
            else
            {
                pixels[i][j]=1;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: It is also increasing my array index numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably introduce a method which somehow evaluates 4x4 array of pixels into `0` or `1`, e.g. based on average luminosity:

```
public static void printAllARGBDetails(BufferedImage image) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();
    System.out.println("Image Dimension: Height-" + height + ", Width-"
            + width);
    System.out.println("Total Pixels: " + (height * width));
    int pixels[][]=new int[21][21];
    int pixel=width/21;
    System.out.println("Pixel=" +pixel);

    for (int i = 20; i>=0 ; i--) {
        for (int j = 20; j>=0 ; j--) {
                pixels[i][j] = getPixel (image, i, j);
                System.out.println(String.format ("Pixel[%d,%d]=%d", i, j, pixels[i][j]));
        }
    } 
}

private static final long LUMINOSITY_THRESHOLD = 23000;

private static int getPixel (BufferedImage image, int i, int j) {
   long totalLuminosity = 0;
   for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
      for (int m = 0; m < 4; m++) {
          long luminosity = getLuminosity (image.getRGB (i*4 + k, j*4 + m));
          totalLuminosity += luminosity;
      }
   }

   return totalLuminosity/16 > LUMINOSITY_THRESHOLD ? 0 : 1;
}

private static int getLuminosity (int rgb) {
    int r = rgb >> 16;
    int g = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
    int b = rgb & 0xFF;

    int luminosity = 21*r + 71*g + 7*b;

    return luminosity;
}
```

Comment: No Luminosity is not the case. I only want to get colour module size by module size which is width/21. I tried your code and it gave the exactly same result as mine.

Comment: @Berkan The way I understood your question is that you have a QR21 code stored in a 294x294 image. So essentially you have to convert the fullscale image into 21x21 black&white image. And this is exactly what the code I proposed is doing.